# CSS Bootstrap: Having a background overflow the visible area

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a page using Boostrap 3.  I've got one section of content that is offset by 4 columns with some white space.  I have an image/background that measures 1200 pixels wide that I want to butt up against the column, but extend beyond the page to the left.

My goal is to have it sot hat if the user extends the browser horizontally, more of the background will be displayed, but never allow it to overlap the content.

Any thoughts on how to pull this off?

Here's my code:

```
<style>
    section#moreFeatures {
        background-image: url(/img/Backgrounds/moreFeatures.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: -540px 50%;
    }
</style>

<section id="moreFeatures" class="with-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-5">
                <h1>
                    Simple, Effective, and Elegant.
                    <br><small>Without sacrificing robust features.</small>
                </h1>
                <br>    
                <br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a ipsum sit amet metus blandit vestibulum. Cras et mauris eros. Nam sed eros at orci imperdiet pharetra. Pellentesque volutpat luctus lorem, quis sodales felis auctor vitae. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus in purus magna. Etiam blandit neque ac pulvinar tincidunt. Morbi porta porttitor neque in tempus. Cras volutpat, enim sed vulputate accumsan, lectus sapien semper leo, sit amet malesuada erat sapien at dolor. Nullam nibh tellus, fermentum non elit et, ultrices hendrerit est.</p>
                <p>Quisque mollis nunc sagittis tellus molestie, at suscipit nulla posuere. Fusce interdum eu eros vel rutrum. Proin id arcu convallis, iaculis arcu sed, rutrum ligula. Aliquam dignissim faucibus ultrices. Sed facilisis ipsum vel tempus condimentum. Phasellus molestie ut risus et iaculis. Nulla sem tellus, consequat a magna pharetra, aliquet tincidunt eros. Cras velit lectus, lacinia nec nisi at, eleifend egestas sem. Aenean egestas dictum dui, eget mollis magna viverra imperdiet. Integer consequat libero dui, vitae viverra nunc malesuada adipiscing. Aliquam ac urna at sem placerat auctor.</p>
                <p>Duis eleifend tellus libero, eu varius tortor congue nec. Maecenas egestas metus ut adipiscing ultrices. Curabitur sit amet arcu massa. Curabitur a sapien sit amet lorem feugiat tristique a ut augue. Aliquam in elit vel quam sagittis viverra vel eu odio. Integer mi sem, lacinia id ullamcorper id, elementum ac lacus. Curabitur ante dolor, viverra ut libero vel, vulputate vulputate orci. Proin mollis felis in erat vulputate, ut ornare tellus porta. Donec tristique fermentum velit vel ultrices. Curabitur sed sapien ipsum. In sed odio malesuada, ornare lacus eget, elementum est. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque vel rutrum nunc, id feugiat lorem. Nunc auctor dapibus ligula vel imperdiet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: please put sample of jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you tried placing the background in a col-md-4 before your content div instead of offseting it? Would be a much simpler solution...

Comment: I did.  The issue is that I want the background to be applied to the section instead of a column so that the design bleeds left off the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that you can't place a background outside of the container it's designated in.

That being said, I got this working via jQuery and some creative use of positive padding mixed with negative margin.  Here's my solution.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var backgroundWidth = 1052; // Width of the background image //
        var containerGutter = ($(window).width() - $('div#moreFeaturesContainer').width()) / 2;
        var columnGutter = parseInt($('div#simpleEffectiveElegant').css('margin-left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''));

        var backgroundPosition = backgroundWidth - containerGutter - columnGutter;

        $('section#moreFeatures').css('margin-left', '-' + backgroundPosition+ 'px');
        $('section#moreFeatures').css('padding-left', backgroundPosition + 'px');

        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            var backgroundWidth = 1052;
            var containerGutter = ($(window).width() - $('div#moreFeaturesContainer').width()) / 2;
            var columnGutter = parseInt($('div#simpleEffectiveElegant').css('margin-left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''));

            var backgroundPosition = backgroundWidth - containerGutter - columnGutter;

            $('section#moreFeatures').css('margin-left', '-' + backgroundPosition + 'px');
            $('section#moreFeatures').css('padding-left', backgroundPosition + 'px');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use -

```
section#moreFeatures {
    background: #dbdbdb url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/1600) fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Click for **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/g7fS7/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, not the effect I am looking for.  What I need looks like this: http://app.socialact.com/Temp/t.jpg whereas the text will always occupy columns 4-12 in my 12 column grid, but the background connects to the left side of that content column.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS only solution involving having a div instead of an offset and displaying the image with an image tag rather than as a background.
The trick here is to use `direction:rtl` so that the overflowing image goes to the left.

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/csbXfZmLRtDHcOjgd3It?p=preview

CSS

```
.overflow {
  text-align:right;
  overflow:visible;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-5 overflow'>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/1600">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7">
        <h1>
                Simple, Effective, and Elegant.
                              <br />
          <small>Without sacrificing robust features.</small>
        </h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a ipsum sit amet metus blandit vestibulum. Cras et mauris eros. Nam sed eros at orci imperdiet pharetra. Pellentesque volutpat luctus lorem, quis sodales felis auctor vitae. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus in purus magna. Etiam blandit neque ac pulvinar tincidunt. Morbi porta porttitor neque in tempus. Cras volutpat, enim sed vulputate accumsan, lectus sapien semper leo, sit amet malesuada erat sapien at dolor. Nullam nibh tellus, fermentum non elit et, ultrices hendrerit est.</p>
        <p>Quisque mollis nunc sagittis tellus molestie, at suscipit nulla posuere. Fusce interdum eu eros vel rutrum. Proin id arcu convallis, iaculis arcu sed, rutrum ligula. Aliquam dignissim faucibus ultrices. Sed facilisis ipsum vel tempus condimentum. Phasellus molestie ut risus et iaculis. Nulla sem tellus, consequat a magna pharetra, aliquet tincidunt eros. Cras velit lectus, lacinia nec nisi at, eleifend egestas sem. Aenean egestas dictum dui, eget mollis magna viverra imperdiet. Integer consequat libero dui, vitae viverra nunc malesuada adipiscing. Aliquam ac urna at sem placerat auctor.</p>
        <p>Duis eleifend tellus libero, eu varius tortor congue nec. Maecenas egestas metus ut adipiscing ultrices. Curabitur sit amet arcu massa. Curabitur a sapien sit amet lorem feugiat tristique a ut augue. Aliquam in elit vel quam sagittis viverra vel eu odio. Integer mi sem, lacinia id ullamcorper id, elementum ac lacus. Curabitur ante dolor, viverra ut libero vel, vulputate vulputate orci. Proin mollis felis in erat vulputate, ut ornare tellus porta. Donec tristique fermentum velit vel ultrices. Curabitur sed sapien ipsum. In sed odio malesuada, ornare lacus eget, elementum est. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque vel rutrum nunc, id feugiat lorem. Nunc auctor dapibus ligula vel imperdiet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```